# Initialization of static method when class loads in java

Tags: java

I have a doubt regarding static methods. In the program written below, output will be: `main`. I understand this because `main` is a static method, so when class loads, it executes. If so, the same principle should apply for `met()` also, right? As it is also static. Why does only `main` executes whereas `met()` doesn't when the class loads?

```
public class Test {

    static void met() {
        System.out.println("method");    
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("main");    
    }    
}
```

Comment: Because it is `main()`.

Comment: `main(String[])` is the first method called.  It has to be static, but that doesn't mean all static method are called.  It also has to return `void` but that does not mean all method which return `void` are called. It has to have a `String[]` as the only argument, but that doesn't mean all method with `String[]` are called either.

Comment: `main` is a special method. It is invoked by JVM on startup. Check out [Java Language Specification. Chapter 12. Execution.](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-12.html#jls-12)

Comment: Please check my answer, I explained what static methods are.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`main()` method is not executed because it's *static*, it executes because it is the [Entry Point](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Main_function) for any Java program. If you want something to run, you'll need to call it from the main method. No other methods are automatically called when the class is executed.

Comment: However a static block can run automatically. Please check in my answer. I have explained the concept of static methods & static block.

Comment: Based on his question, he was under the assumption that any static method would automatically get called when the class was executed. He didn't realize main() was a special method. So yes static blocks can run automatically, but that is irrelevant to his point of confusion.

Comment: *Nothing ELSE gets executed automatically* This statement may put OP in some other confusion. So it needs some elaboration.

Comment: **It is relevant** to his confusion because he is confusing the two as *one and the same*. So you should by right be explaining **both**. If you only explain why the `main` method executes as an entry point, then the asker is left to wonder about those "static blocks" he heard about. *Was he wrong?* **Now he has a new but related source of confusion.** A clear-cut answer explaining `main` method, `static` methods and `static` blocks and all their differences clears up all the confusion and is always a better answer.

Comment: I disagree that more information is always the best answer and I still contend that his main misunderstanding was the concept of an an Entry Point. I think too many of the answers focused on what happens when a class loads, while the question probably was meant to be about what happens when a class executes.

Comment: "Nothing else gets executed automatically." - this isn't true.

Comment: @studro thanks for the feedback, I've updated that last statement to be more precise.

Comment: I wonder you said thanks to studro, because he said the same which me and @ADTC were saying

Comment: I never said that more information is better. If that was so the best answer would be a lengthy one which runs into volumes explaining everything in the universe! Obviously that isn't so. What I said is that the best answer is one that briefly addresses **all** points of concern regarding the question. Not just one aspect. That's where your answer fails, because you only address one aspect (entry point) while completely ignoring another aspect (static blocks vs static methods). Both aspects are talked about by the asker, so both are to be discussed in the answer. I think the votes agree.

Answer (score 18):

No, this isn't correct.

Neither of these methods are called when the class is loaded.

`main()` is called when you execute the class `Test`.

Only static initialisers are called when the class is loaded. A static initialiser looks like this:

```
static
{
    //code here
}
```

A class is loaded before the `main()` method is executed, and therefore its static initialiser is run before the `main()` method. The following snippet will make that clear.

```
public class TestA
{
    static
    {
        System.out.println( "hello" );
    }

    public static void main( String[] args )
    {
        System.out.println( "bye" );
    }
}
```

Comment: Simple and effective explanation.! +1

Comment: You followed the KISS principle, covering all aspects in as few words as possible. Love it, kudos!

Answer (score 9):

### Let me explain it in detail

**Types of methods** There are basically two types of methods,

1. Instance methods
2. Class Methods

**Instance Methods** Belong to objects and you will always need an object/instance to call such methods.

**static methods** are the class methods and they can be called directly by class name, there is no need to have an instance of class to call them.

For example,

```
class Demo{
    public void sayHello(){
         System.out.println("Hello");
    }

    public static void sayHi(){
         System.out.println("Hi")
    }

    public static void main(String args[]){
          Demo.sayHi();    //Call to static/class method

          Demo.sayHello(); //It will not work

          Demo d = new Demo();
          d.sayHello();    //It will work.
    }
}
```

`**But NONE of them gets called automatically when class loads.**`

**Main Difference between the two**

In memory there is ONLY ONE copy of static methods which will be available for all the objects. But whenever an object is created a new copy of instance method is created for the object, so each object has its own instance method. Similar to instance & class variables.

Static methods are not meant to be run automatically, instead they are shared by all objects. Why `main()` method is called, because it is the **entry point** of the program.

Apart from them, there is **static block** which is called automatically only once when the class is loaded.

Example

```
class Main{
     static{
           System.out.println("static block");
     }

     public static void main(String args[]){
           System.out.println("main");
     }
}
```

**Output** will be

static block

main

Comment: A bit of clean-up is necessary but a great and well-rounded answer. Kudos for covering all aspects!

Answer (score 5):

Not at all. The main method will only run if that particular class is ran as entry point.

That met() method will not run until it has been called. The main difference it has with instance methods, is that you do not need to create an instance of the class in order to run it, you can simply run it through the class itself: `Test.met();`

What you mean is a static block:

```
private static String description;

static{
  description = "this runs on loading the class";
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use `static block` instead of static method, to print it before main method like this -

```
public class Test
{

static{
 System.out.println("method");
}

public static void main(String[] args){
   System.out.println("main");
}

}
```

Answer (score 2):

`met()` is a static method, it will be in memory when the class is loaded, you need to call it.. You could use a `static block` to print "method".

Answer (score 2):

If you want to execute on load , just intialise it as `static` block,

```
static{
System.out.println("method");    
}
```

Because static blocks are executed once the class loads . And among other static methods `main()` has the high priority

Answer (score 1):

**No** static method will get called when you call it only,  you are mixing static initializer and static method

it prints main because when you run Java application it invokes `main()` method

Answer (score 1):

Not all static method will be called by default when a program runs.

From Docs

```
The java tool launches a Java application. It does this by starting a Java runtime environment, loading a
specified class, and invoking that class's main method. The method declaration must look like the following:

  **public static void main(String args[])**
```

So, main will be called by JVM and someone should call met() so that it is executed.

Comment: **Side note:** A varargs-based declaration is also allowed in Java versions that support it. Example: `public static void main(String... args)`. In any case "must look like" is only a guideline. The only rule is that it should be public, it should be static, it should return void, it must be named main, and it's argument is one String array. The rest is up to you, so this is entirely correct: `static public void main(String[] wondrousThings) throws CrappyThingsException, SomeOtherException`

Answer (score 1):

there is a difference between static methods, static blocks and static variables. As you do not call the static method, it will not print

To make it print you will need to call `Test.met ();`

Alternatively you could have it set as a static block

as in

```
static {
   System.out.println("static block");
}
```

This will be called as soon as Test is loaded.

Answer (score 1):

`Main()` is only executed because it is the entry point.

For more information you can [read the documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/deployment/jar/appman.html).

Answer (score 1):

What you understood is wrong. Because whenever class loads `JVM` creates Class class object and int that class class object all static methods resides. main method is entry point for JVM thats why it is executing, JVM internally calling Main method. Whenever Class loads that time it only executes Static internalization blocks.